# Writing test for race condition

Tags: python, django, multithreading, pytest, race-condition

I want to write unit test to check if race condition happens when multiple users send request at the same time. I'm using `pytest`.
I have tried `threading` module of python and it didn't work. What is the standard solution?

Comment: Why do you think a UnitTest ist the correct vehicle for testing a race condition?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I've no idea how to test it! What do you suggest?

Comment: @AminA2 I use this decorator for concurrent testing: https://gist.github.com/mvmocanu/6020200. Also read this article for usage: https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/05/26/testing-django-views-for-concurrency-issues/.